# optimize mongoid find query performance

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, sharding

I have a mongo collection which is stores user_id(foreign key) and address_id(foreign key). The collection currently holds more than 5 million records. I have 3 shards and the collection is sharded as

```
db.adminCommand({shardCollection: "my_db.user_addresses", key: { user_id: 1, address_id: 1}})
```

the explain query states

```
pp UserAddress.where(id: '5ace54343b816c0cdf4b2aa9').explain
{"queryPlanner"=>
  {"mongosPlannerVersion"=>1,
   "winningPlan"=>
    {"stage"=>"SHARD_MERGE",
     "shards"=>
      [{"shardName"=>"ShardOne",
        "connectionString"=>
         "ShardOne/ip-xxx-xx-0-111:17018,ip-xxx-xx-9-99:17017",
        "serverInfo"=>
         {"host"=>"ip-xxx-xx-9-99",
          "port"=>17017,
          "version"=>"3.6.3",
          "gitVersion"=>"9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"},
        "plannerVersion"=>1,
        "namespace"=>"my_db.user_addresses",
        "indexFilterSet"=>false,
        "parsedQuery"=>
         {"_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5ace54343b816c0cdf4b2aa9')}},
        "winningPlan"=>
         {"stage"=>"SHARDING_FILTER", "inputStage"=>{"stage"=>"IDHACK"}},
        "rejectedPlans"=>[]},
       {"shardName"=>"ShardTwo",
        "connectionString"=>
         "ShardTwo/ip-xxx-xx-9-222:11018,ip-xxx-xx-9-66:11017",
        "serverInfo"=>
         {"host"=>"ip-xxx-xx-9-66",
          "port"=>11017,
          "version"=>"3.6.3",
          "gitVersion"=>"9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"},
        "plannerVersion"=>1,
        "namespace"=>"my_db.user_addresses",
        "indexFilterSet"=>false,
        "parsedQuery"=>
         {"_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5ace54343b816c0cdf4b2aa9')}},
        "winningPlan"=>
         {"stage"=>"SHARDING_FILTER", "inputStage"=>{"stage"=>"IDHACK"}},
        "rejectedPlans"=>[]},
       {"shardName"=>"ShardThree",
        "connectionString"=>
         "ShardThree/ip-xxx-xx-9-143:88888,ip-xxx-xx-0-87:88887",
        "serverInfo"=>
         {"host"=>"ip-xxx-xx-0-87",
          "port"=>88887,
          "version"=>"3.6.3",
          "gitVersion"=>"9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"},
        "plannerVersion"=>1,
        "namespace"=>"my_db.user_addresses",
        "indexFilterSet"=>false,
        "parsedQuery"=>
         {"_id"=>{"$eq"=>BSON::ObjectId('5ace54343b816c0cdf4b2aa9')}},
        "winningPlan"=>
         {"stage"=>"SHARDING_FILTER", "inputStage"=>{"stage"=>"IDHACK"}},
        "rejectedPlans"=>[]}]}},
 "executionStats"=>
  {"nReturned"=>1,
   "executionTimeMillis"=>1,
   "totalKeysExamined"=>1,
   "totalDocsExamined"=>1,
   "executionStages"=>
    {"stage"=>"SHARD_MERGE",
     "nReturned"=>1,
     "executionTimeMillis"=>1,
     "totalKeysExamined"=>1,
     "totalDocsExamined"=>1,
     "totalChildMillis"=>0,
     "shards"=>
      [{"shardName"=>"ShardOne",
        "executionSuccess"=>true,
        "executionStages"=>
         {"stage"=>"SHARDING_FILTER",
          "nReturned"=>0,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
          "works"=>1,
          "advanced"=>0,
          "needTime"=>0,
          "needYield"=>0,
          "saveState"=>0,
          "restoreState"=>0,
          "isEOF"=>1,
          "invalidates"=>0,
          "chunkSkips"=>0,
          "inputStage"=>
           {"stage"=>"IDHACK",
            "nReturned"=>0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
            "works"=>1,
            "advanced"=>0,
            "needTime"=>0,
            "needYield"=>0,
            "saveState"=>0,
            "restoreState"=>0,
            "isEOF"=>1,
            "invalidates"=>0,
            "keysExamined"=>0,
            "docsExamined"=>0}}},
       {"shardName"=>"ShardTwo",
        "executionSuccess"=>true,
        "executionStages"=>
         {"stage"=>"SHARDING_FILTER",
          "nReturned"=>0,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
          "works"=>1,
          "advanced"=>0,
          "needTime"=>0,
          "needYield"=>0,
          "saveState"=>0,
          "restoreState"=>0,
          "isEOF"=>1,
          "invalidates"=>0,
          "chunkSkips"=>0,
          "inputStage"=>
           {"stage"=>"IDHACK",
            "nReturned"=>0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
            "works"=>1,
            "advanced"=>0,
            "needTime"=>0,
            "needYield"=>0,
            "saveState"=>0,
            "restoreState"=>0,
            "isEOF"=>1,
            "invalidates"=>0,
            "keysExamined"=>0,
            "docsExamined"=>0}}},
       {"shardName"=>"ShardThree",
        "executionSuccess"=>true,
        "executionStages"=>
         {"stage"=>"SHARDING_FILTER",
          "nReturned"=>1,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
          "works"=>2,
          "advanced"=>1,
          "needTime"=>0,
          "needYield"=>0,
          "saveState"=>0,
          "restoreState"=>0,
          "isEOF"=>1,
          "invalidates"=>0,
          "chunkSkips"=>0,
          "inputStage"=>
           {"stage"=>"IDHACK",
            "nReturned"=>1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate"=>0,
            "works"=>1,
            "advanced"=>1,
            "needTime"=>0,
            "needYield"=>0,
            "saveState"=>0,
            "restoreState"=>0,
            "isEOF"=>1,
            "invalidates"=>0,
            "keysExamined"=>1,
            "docsExamined"=>1}}}]},
   "allPlansExecution"=>
    [{"shardName"=>"ShardOne", "allPlans"=>[]},
     {"shardName"=>"ShardTwo", "allPlans"=>[]},
     {"shardName"=>"ShardThree", "allPlans"=>[]}]},
 "ok"=>1.0,
 "$clusterTime"=>
  {"clusterTime"=>
    #<BSON::Timestamp:0x31dbca5d @increment=475, @seconds=1523618199>,
   "signature"=>
    {"hash"=><BSON::Binary:0x2786 type=generic data=0x57ecb8e45eee5178...>,
     "keyId"=>6537488309583609875}},
 "operationTime"=>
  #<BSON::Timestamp:0x21ebf9be @increment=474, @seconds=1523618199>}
```

the problem is that new relic states that this is the most timeconsuming query of all the database queries.

```
Avg response time: 50,100 ms
Min: 1.37ms
Max: 62400 ms
Throughput: 104 cpm
```

How do we optimize the find query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Min: 1.37ms, Max: 62400 ms` suggests the problem is not with the query itself but with the cluster, e.g. when one of the shards hangs for a minute. `"stage"=>"IDHACK"` basically says it would be tricky to optimize it more.

I fail to see why you shard it at the first place. 5mln documents x 50 bytes each takes less than half-GB. You can easily fit into memory of a single shard and make the query blazing fast with covered index.

Comment: the 5mln docs are a tip of the iceberg. I need to migrate around 350 mln docs. this is in reference to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605000/dump-elasticsearch-2-x-to-mongodb-and-back-to-es-6-x

Comment: Say, if i take the backup of the database and dump is again based on new shard keys or no shard keys, will it work?. The documents the collection contains only these 2 foreign keys. Since the table would contain huge amount of records, we decided to shard it.

Comment: Fair enough. 350mln is slightly larger than 5mln. Is embedding ids an option? I get it as you have n:m relation, but with sharded collection you can't use lookup, which will make it quite inconvenient to use.  The only way to improve this particular query is to make sharding key based on id hash, so the query hits a single shard. It will reduce chances of long response by 3 but will likely affect performance of other queries.

Comment: Enbedding is not an option because the number of associated records is huge. anyways, will it work if a backedup mongodb database is restored based on new shard key or no shard key?

Comment: You cannot have a sharded collection without a shard key. You always need exactly 1.